# Set a table to show Information depending multiple selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I need is to display some info depending on multiple values or selections

For example I need to choose a amount of money($1, $10, $50) then a period of time ( 1 day, 10 days, 50 days) and depending of those two values show some information.

The second value (time) change by the first value ( amount of money ) and the final information, depend on the combination of both.

I'm new to javascript and html so I really have idea where to start, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you also need a mysql database and PHP

Comment: wow, that's beyond my knowledge

Comment: @Evoinsec easy peasy | do you have some markup that you can show us? Where do you retrieve your data from? Is all your content static and available before user makes his selections? Where do you get your content from?

Comment: Ok, is basically a table for users to calculate how much money the have to save for a home loan, so user first select the amount of money they need, then the term/time in years in which they want to pay. Those two selections should show some info related to the interest rate. So if I understand you the content is static, I just need it to hide and show depending on the selection

Comment: Is something like this: https://www.hdfc.com/home-loan-emi-calculator  without the ROI value, and users can't input the money amount they just  select from 5 amounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your values are all static, this is doable with just html and js.

HTML - make a spot for the two selections and for the result:

```
<fieldset id="moneyRadios">
    <input id="oneDollar" type="radio" name="money" value="1"><label for="oneDollar">$1</label>
    <input id="tenDollar" type="radio" name="money" value="10"><label for="tenDollar">$10</label>
    <input id="fiftyDollar" type="radio" name="money" value="50"><label for="fiftyDollar">$50</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="dayRadios">
</fieldset>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS - first make the money radios do something when clicked

```
var moneyInputs = document.getElementById('moneyRadios').getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i =0; i < moneyInputs.length; i++)
    {
        moneyInputs[i].addEventListener('click',moneyClicked, false);
    }
```

Second, send which money radio was clicked and clear the result

```
function moneyClicked(moneyRadios) {
        var moneySelected = document.querySelector('input[name = "money"]:checked').value;
        setDayOptions(moneySelected);               
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML ='';
    }
```

Now, you said that the day options would change depending on which money value the user picks, but you only gave one set of day options. I made up some day options for each money value, so modify `dayOptions` to your needs with the format `'moneyValue':[dayOption1,dayOption2,dayOption3]`. Then use the money value to make some Day radios and put them in the appropriate fieldset. Then add a click event to the newly made radios.

```
function setDayOptions(dollars){
        var dayOptions = {'1':[1,10,50], '10':[2,20,100], '50':[3,30,150]};
        var daysFieldset = document.getElementById('dayRadios');
        var selectedDayOptions = dayOptions[dollars];
        daysFieldset.innerHTML='';
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedDayOptions.length; ++i) {

            var dayRad = document.createElement('input');
            dayRad.type='radio';
            dayRad.id='days'+selectedDayOptions[i];
            dayRad.name='day';
            dayRad.value=selectedDayOptions[i];

            var dayRadLabel = document.createElement('label');
            dayRadLabel.htmlFor='days'+selectedDayOptions[i];
            var labelText = document.createTextNode(selectedDayOptions[i]+' Days');
            dayRadLabel.appendChild(labelText);         

            daysFieldset.appendChild(dayRad);
            daysFieldset.appendChild(dayRadLabel);
        }
        var dayInputs = document.getElementById('dayRadios').getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i =0; i < dayInputs.length; i++)
        {
            dayInputs[i].addEventListener('click',dayClicked, false);
        }
    }
```

Finally, do something when a day radio is clicked. You can use the selected values to generate a table, or show a particular pre-made table, or whatever you like. I just displayed the selections and made a rate out of them.

```
function dayClicked(){
        var moneySelected = document.querySelector('input[name = "money"]:checked').value;
        var daysSelected = document.querySelector('input[name = "day"]:checked').value;
        var rate = moneySelected/daysSelected;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<p>Money: $'+moneySelected+' Days: '+daysSelected+' is $'+rate+' per day</p>';
    }
```

You can see all the code working here: https://jsfiddle.net/fz44mpmo/4/

Comment: @IcHatter This is a awesome answer, really well explained, you undertood exactly what I need, just one more question, by selecting the combination of the two values can I display a simple html <table> by calling it ID? For example: 

$1 combined with 1day = display a <table id="table1">
$1 combined with 10days = display a <table id="table2">
etc.

Comment: Sure. Look at [How to change the display of a div using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246273/)